# How to successfully resolve multiple pulsation frequencies in the FFT?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, dft, pulse

I am dealing with signals that in both extreme cases can have:

a) Non-overlapping monochromatic pulsation-like events at different points within a time series.

b) Overlapping pulsations at multiple frequencies for the entirety of the signal

Code to create these dummy signals is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

def test_pulse(start,end,periods, noise=0, npts=3600, dt=1.0, phase = [0],\
               amp=[1],window='hann'):
    #Generate waves at indices start and end, at frequencies (periods)

    t = np.arange(npts, dtype=float) * dt
    
    x = np.zeros(npts)
        
    for p,a,ph in zip(periods,amp,phase):
        
        wave_t = np.arange(end-start)
        
        w=getattr(signal.windows,window)(end-start)
        
        x[start:end] += a* np.cos(2 * np.pi * wave_t / p + ph*np.ones(end-start)) * w
        x += noise * np.random.randn(npts)

    return t, x
```

In an idealized overlapping case where frequencies of interest are in the frequency resolution of my signal, I can clearly see peaks in the correct places. However, for the non-overlapping case there is a lot more spectral leakage which I anticipate, but the peaks are now not lining up:

[image]

For my application getting the correct peaks is important, so what techniques can we use to correctly identify non-overlapping monochromatic frequencies within a signal using the FFT?

Code to produce the plot above is as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,4))

freqs =np.fft.rfftfreq(3600,1)
freqs = ulf[(ulf>1e-3) & (ulf<=10e-3)]

F = freqs[10:30:6]

#Overlapping for entirety of signal
t, x = test_pulse(0,3600,[1/f for f in F], noise=0, npts=3600, dt=1.0, phase = np.zeros(F.size),amp=np.ones(F.size),window='hann')

sFT = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(signal.hilbert(x),n=3600))
all_freqs = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(x.size))
y = abs(sFT)/x.size

ax[1].plot(all_freqs,y,label='Overlap')
ax[0].plot(t,x)

#Non-overlapping pulses within signal
t, x = test_pulse(0,900,[1/f for f in F[:1]], noise=0, npts=3600, dt=1.0, phase = np.zeros(1),\
               amp=[1],window='hann')

for s,e,f in zip([900,1800,2700],[1800,2700,3600],F[1:]):
    x+=test_pulse(s,e,[1/f], noise=0, npts=3600, dt=1.0, phase = np.zeros(1),\
               amp=[1],window='hann')[1]
ax[0].plot(t,x)
sFT = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(signal.hilbert(x),n=3600))
all_freqs = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(x.size))
y = abs(sFT)/x.size

ax[1].plot(all_freqs,y,label='Non-overlap')

[ax[1].axvline(ff,ls='--',color='black') for ff in F]
ax[1].set_xlabel('f (Hz)')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax[1].set_xlim(0,12e-3)
ax[1].legend()

ax[0].set_xlabel('t')
```

Comment: Its hard to tell how many periods the bursts are.  Could you also plot the time domain data?  It also looks like you are adding the noise in every time through loop.  So maybe you have 3 times the amount of noise that you were thinking.

Comment: I have added figures for the signals in the time domain. In both cases I have actually set the noise to zero for illustration. The bursts are all in seconds (900) as opposed to periods. I did also try with integer multiples of periods (still non-overlapping) but the same issue occurred